# ¿Como salir de un Bucle con contador en Java?

Tags: java, bucles

He hecho un pequeño programa en el que se debe introducir una contraseña y si llega a un máximo de tres intentos fallidos pues el programa finaliza sin mas. Mi problema es que con mi actual código no consigo llegar a ningún sitio, el bucle  se repite de forma infinita. Gracias de antemano por la ayuda, llevo muy poco tiempo programando en JAVA y no se como proseguir.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class prueba {

public static void main (String[]args) {

    String clave="Juan";
    String pass="";
    int conteo=0;

    while ((clave.equals(pass)==false)||(conteo==3)) {

        pass=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la contraseña");

    if (clave.equals(pass)==false) {
        System.out.println("Contraseña Incorrecta");
        conteo++;
    if (conteo==3) {
        System.out.println("EQUIPO BLOQUEADO");
    }
    }


    }
    System.out.println("CONTRASEÑA CORRECTA");
}
}
```

Comment: Deberias intentar cambiar el || por un  &&.

Comment: @VirusDetected igual esta mal. mira las condiciones.. conteo deberia ser <= 3..

Comment: La condición del ciclo es incorrecta. intenta con `(!clave.equals(pass))&&(conteo<3)`

Comment: igual va a salir el carte de contraseña correcta.. pase lo que pase...

Comment: @gbianchi Conseguí salir del bucle, gracias ! sabía que si o si iba a imprimirme en pantalla el contraseña correcta, es solo que no conseguía salir de ese bucle y quería saber como... muchas gracias!

Comment: @VRivers5 puedes conseguir salir del bucle pero como comenta gbianchi siempre se mostrará "contraseña correcta" , debes modificar tu código , te sugiero revises la documentación que agrego, saludos.

Comment: metele. un break en donde quieresque se ropa el bucle

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de @JorgeSys (sorry no se enlazar usuarios aún xD) es muy completa.
Para reducir líneas también puedes utilizar la instrucción break que rompas el bucle y usar do {} while. También es mejor guardar el éxito en un boolean y no tener que estar comparando String innecesariamente.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String clave = "Juan";
    String pass = "";
    int conteo = 0;

    boolean exito = false;
    do {
        pass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la contraseña");
        if (clave.equals(pass)) {
            exito = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Contraseña Incorrecta");
            conteo++;
            if (conteo == 3) {
                System.out.println("EQUIPO BLOQUEADO");
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (!exito);

    if (exito) {
        System.out.println("CONTRASEÑA CORRECTA");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es demasiado importante revises la siguiente teoría :

- [**Operadores lógicos y sentencias de control, Bucles en  Java**](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ssa/java/tutorials/j-introtojava1/index.html)

Primeramente debes saber que esto :

```
clave.equals(pass)==false
```

lo puedes reducir a :

```
!clave.equals(pass)
```

ya que el método `equals()` en realidad esta realizando una evaluación, si `clave` es igual a `pass`. Si agregamos `!` indica que lo estamos negando, por lo tanto significa que `clave` NO es igual a `pass`.

Ahora el problema principal por el cual se realiza un bucle infinito es que al iniciar en realidad siempre `clave` será diferente a `pass`

```
while ((!clave.equals(pass))||(conteo==3)) {
```

---

Lo que debes hacer es evaluar el valor de `pass` antes de iniciar el bucle, si la contraseña es incorrecta vuelve a pedir el valor a el usuario:

```
 pass=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la contraseña");

    while ((!clave.equals(pass))||(conteo==3)) {        

      if (!clave.equals(pass)) {
        System.out.println("Contraseña Incorrecta");
        pass=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la contraseña");        
        conteo++;
      }

    }
```

en caso de llegar a ser igual el valor de `clave` y `pass` o (`||`) que el valor de `conteo` sea igual a 3, terminará el bucle.

Ahora aquí puedes evaluar si la contraseña fue correcta o simplemente se bloqueó el equipo:

```
if (clave.equals(pass)) { 
    System.out.println("CONTRASEÑA CORRECTA");         
}else{
    System.out.println("EQUIPO BLOQUEADO");
}
```

---

Analiza el código:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class prueba {

public static void main (String[]args) {

    String clave="Juan";
    String pass="";
    int conteo=0;

    pass=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la contraseña");

    while ((!clave.equals(pass))||(conteo==3)) {        

      if (!clave.equals(pass)) {
        System.out.println("Contraseña Incorrecta");
        pass=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la contraseña");        
        conteo++;
      }

    }    

    //Después de terminarse el bucle, revisa...
    if (clave.equals(pass)) { //Si la contraseña es correcta.
        System.out.println("CONTRASEÑA CORRECTA");         
    }else{//Nunca fue correcta, bloquea el equipo
        System.out.println("EQUIPO BLOQUEADO");
    }

}
```